# Combining all the cell in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have variable cell in which the image patches are stored in this way:
[image]

I want to combine all these cells like it should 834 x 1.
I am confuse how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer assumes that you have separate cell arrays as variables.  If this is the case, then this is perfectly fine.  However, you mentioned that you have a nested cell array where each element is a cell array.  If this is the case, the accepted answer is not correct.

The correct way to do this would be to use [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) and extract out all of your cells as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) so that you can create one final cell array that combines all of your nested cells together.  Assuming your original nested cell array is stored in `C`, you would create a new cell array `Cout` that extracts each element and creates one final cell array:

```
Cout = vertcat(C{:});
```

Answer (score -1):

I you have multiple regions:

```
C1 = {1, 2, 3};
C2 = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
C3 = {10, 20, 30};
```

Concatenate cell arrays with the array concatenation operator, `[]`. In this example, vertically concatenate the cell arrays by separating them with semicolons:

```
C4 = [C1; C2; C3]
```

Comment: The OP has a nested cell array of cells.  They are not in separate variables as you have assumed.